# Distance measurements and tf

Tags: ros, sensor, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I monitor a small robot with a number of external distance sensors. The sensors are implemented as ROS nodes publishing their results. Now I want to integrate a mechanism that allows a transformation of the measurements related to a known position of the sensor. Short

Distance measurements + Sensor Position = correct representation in the world

I guess their exists a solution for this problem in ROS?

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10603/distance-measurements-and-tf/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Best way is probably to use [URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file) and [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) to define and publish your robot description, including sensor location, to tf.

Then, if you publish your sensor data using one of the message types with a [built-in rviz display](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes) (e.g. sensor_msgs/Range) you will be able to easily visualize it on 3D.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-19**:
There's also a Range datatype defined in sensor_msgs http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html for which there are rviz visualizers in the nxt packages and soon will be built into rviz.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you've already noticed, tf is the tool you want. Define frames for your various items, publish the transforms between them, and you're good to go. See the tf tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-14**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf